# traversing in linked list

Tags: python, data-structures

I was writing the code for traversing through the linked list but not getting the desired output. 
 The code is provided let me know the problem

```
class Node :
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class Linklist :
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insert(self,newNode):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = newNode
        else:
            lastNode = self.head
            while True:
                if lastNode is None:
                    break
                lastNode = lastNode.next
            lastNode.next = newNode

    def printlinklist(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("list is empty")
            return
        currentNode = self.head
        while True:
            if currentNode is None:
                break
            print(currentNode.data)
            currentNode = currentNode.next


linklist = Linklist()

firstNode = Node("Aradhya")
linklist.insert(firstNode)

secondNode = Node("Sheila")
linklist.insert(secondNode)

thirdNode = Node("Diya")
linklist.insert(thirdNode)        

linklist.printlinklist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!! You need to do this simple modification in the `insert()` method:

```
def insert(self,newNode):
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = newNode
    else:
        lastNode = self.head
        while lastNode.next:      #<-- change this instead of `while True`
            #if lastNode is None: #<--- there is no point for this line
            #    break            #<--- there is no point for this line#
            lastNode = lastNode.next
        lastNode.next = newNode
```